# Is it needed to learn JSX?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I know HTML, CSS & JS. I need to learn react, and I have heard about [HTML to JSX extension.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=riazxrazor.html-to-jsx)

So, is it necessary to learn JSX?

Comment: It will make your life easier. But you can do it without: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html. However this sort of question is subjective, instead - "How can I use React without JSX - here is what I've tried, here is what went wrong" is a better format for this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tool that converts HTML into JSX isn't a substitute for understanding JSX since almost all JSX that you will need in a React application does things beyond outputting something that can be generated from static HTML.

You could, instead, [write the JS that would be generated from JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) directly. This would lose you the benefits of the tool you found while also being harder to learn and manage than JSX.